# Sorting React-table manually using useEffect is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I am trying to use a useEffect in react-table to sort columns manually.  The results have been unexpected and I'm trying to understand what I am missing.

When this is called the first time, at page load, it outputs nothing, as expected.  When I click a column header the first time the change to state.sortBy is detected and is false, as expected, and setFetchSortDirection('Ascending') is hit as expected.  setFetchColumn is also appears to be set to the correct column name as expected. This is where it goes wrong.

both useState's appear empty which is not expected.

when I click the same header again setFetchSortDirection('Descending') appears to be hit as sortBy.Desc is now true.  It is here that fetchSortDirection is set to Ascending.  I don't understand why since the condition for descending was met and "appears" to be hit.

**DataTable.tsx**

```
const [fetchColumn, setFetchColumn] = useState('');
const [fetchSortDirection, setFetchSortDirection] = useState('');
...

useEffect(() => {
        if (state.sortBy.length > 0) {
            if (state.sortBy[0].desc)
                setFetchSortDirection('Descending');

            if (!state.sortBy[0].desc)
                setFetchSortDirection('Ascending');
            else
                setFetchSortDirection('');

            setFetchColumn(state.sortBy[0].id); 
            props.fetchData(fetchColumn, fetchSortDirection);
        } 
        console.log(fetchSortDirection ? fetchSortDirection : "nothing")
    }, [state.sortBy]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the solution

```
const [fetchColumn, setFetchColumn] = useState('');
const [fetchSortDirection, setFetchSortDirection] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (state.sortBy.length > 0) {
    if (state.sortBy[0].desc) {
      setFetchSortDirection('Descending');
    } else {
      setFetchSortDirection('Ascending');
    }
    setFetchColumn(state.sortBy[0].id);
  }
}, [state.sortBy]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (fetchColumn && fetchSortDirection) {
    props.fetchData(fetchColumn, fetchSortDirection);
  }
}, [fetchColumn, fetchSortDirection]);

console.log(fetchSortDirection ? fetchSortDirection : "nothing");
```